# SQL Azure and support for CTE syntax?

Tags: sql-server, azure, common-table-expression, azure-sql-database

Does anyone know if SQL Azure supports CTE syntax? Specifically;

- `WITH`
- `OVER`
- `ROW_NUMBER()`
- `PARTITION BY`

Comment: What specific syntax is CTE-only?

Comment: WITH, OVER, ROW_NUMBER(), PARITION BY

Comment: OVER with ORDER BY isn't supported right now. I coudln't use that to calculate a running total. Also, here is some (maybe outdated) information http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/sql-denali-t-sql-features-in-sql-azure-now/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336270.aspx) - "WITH common_table_expression" is listed as supported. I would assume that means all of the above.