# Is PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY Supported In SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am really struggling with this one and would appreciate any help! I have the SQL statement below which executes perfectly in SQL 2012 but does not execute in Azure with the message:

```
Msg 40517, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Keyword or statement option 'ORDER BY' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

From the Googling I have done PARTITION BY... ORDER BY is supported? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

[SQL Azure and support for CTE syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630606/sql-azure-and-support-for-cte-syntax)

I have pasted the SQL code that is failing below:

```
SELECT        isnull(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.Id), 0) AS Id, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(WEEK, s.SystemWeekId, GETDATE())) AS PredictedYear, DATEPART(MONTH, 
DATEADD(WEEK, s.SystemWeekId, GETDATE())) AS PredictedMonth, s.SystemWeekId AS SystemWeek, s.VehicleId, 
(SUM(s.AverageWeeklyKms) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VehicleId ORDER BY s.Id) + NextServiceKilometres) CalculatedKilometres, 
CAST(CASE WHEN (((FLOOR((SUM(s.AverageWeeklyKms) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VehicleId ORDER BY s.Id) + NextServiceKilometres) / 1000)) * 1000)) % PreventativeKilometreInterval = 0 THEN
    (SELECT        ServiceTypeId
      FROM            ServiceTypes
      WHERE        ServiceTypeDescription =
                                    (SELECT        ParameterValue
                                      FROM            SystemParameters
                                      WHERE        ParameterName = 'PreventativeService')) WHEN (((FLOOR((SUM(s.AverageWeeklyKms) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VehicleId
ORDER BY s.Id) + NextServiceKilometres) / 1000)) * 1000)) % MajorKilometreInterval = 0 THEN
    (SELECT        ServiceTypeId
      FROM            ServiceTypes
      WHERE        ServiceTypeDescription =
                                    (SELECT        ParameterValue
                                      FROM            SystemParameters
                                      WHERE        ParameterName = 'MajorService')) WHEN (((FLOOR((SUM(s.AverageWeeklyKms) OVER (PARTITION BY s.VehicleId
ORDER BY s.Id) + NextServiceKilometres) / 1000)) * 1000)) % MinorKilometreInterval = 0 THEN
    (SELECT        ServiceTypeId
      FROM            ServiceTypes
      WHERE        ServiceTypeDescription =
                                    (SELECT        ParameterValue
                                      FROM            SystemParameters
                                      WHERE        ParameterName = 'MinorService')) ELSE 0 END AS INT) AS ServiceTypeId
FROM            Temp  AS s
```

Comment: Ok so it looks like although the OVER clause is supported it is not a full implementation, I found this blog entry which seems to explain all: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/new-t-sql-2012-scalar-functions-all-but-1-work-in-sql-azure/ and extract below: This isn't a complete implementation of SQL Server 2012's T-SQL improvements in SQL Azure, though. SQL Azure is still waiting for:

1. Sequences
2. UTF-16 collations with supplimentary characters 
3. Windowing (OVER clause enhancements, LAG/LEAD and others, new analytical functions)

Comment: Fo those who need to calculate running totals and cannot use OVER with PARTITIONS and an ORDER BY here is a good resource: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Azure does not support the Partition By... Order By Syntax you will need to use an inner join, here is a very good resource:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server

Answer (score 1):

PARTITION BY... ORDER BY is supported in Azure Sql Database server version V12:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx